# Django: Filter objects by date range

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, models

My object model is :

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to filter all objects for today.

I have one object with start date 2014/03/01 00:00 and end date 2014/10/01 00:00.
I need to have this object when filtering objects by today date ex.:

`Event.objects.filter(start__gte=today, end__lte=today)`

How can I filter objects by today date and get all results where start > today < end ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the today's date from [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) and use `gt` and `lt`:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
Event.objects.filter(start__lt=today, end__gt=today)
```

This would filter objects where start date is less than today and end date is greater than today.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combine method of datetime module:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
Event.objects.filter(start__gte=datetime.datetime.combine(today, datetime.time.min),
                     end__lte=datetime.datetime.combine(today, datetime.time.max))
```