# Get queryset date rage

Tags: python, django

I have 2 fields for start date and end date. 
How to get a rows that falls between the start and end dates.

That my model

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    time_begin = models.TimeField(max_length=255,
                              verbose_name=u'Время начала работы')
    time_end = models.TimeField(max_length=255,
                            verbose_name=u'Время окончания работы')
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742771/django-filter-objects-by-date-range

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django's `filter`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#gte) with [`datetime.time` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#available-types):

```
import datetime
shops = Shop.objects.filter(time_begin__gte=datetime.time(10, 0, 0),
                              time_end__lte=datetime.time(22, 0, 0))
```

Same (`__gte` & `__lte`) can also work for `DateTime` or `Date` fields.
However, if you're using Django 2.2+ you can use the appropriate [built-in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#time) `__time`, `__hour`, `__minute` or `__second` as per need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__lt` and `__gt` filters to target dates in between both.

```
Shop.objects.filter(time_begin__gte=<date>, time_end__lt=<date>)
```

If you're using `DateField` and want to include the end date, use `lte`, otherwise use `lt`.

Comment: ` WHERE (`catalog_shop`.`id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) AND `catalog_shop`.`min_order` <= 10000 AND `catalog_shop`.`time_end` < 22:34:24.999000 AND `catalog_shop`.`time_begin` > 22:34:24.999000)